# How to save details in MongoDb along with image

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mern

I want to save details in mongodb and image in images folder using multer, but I am not getting data in the server

```
const onSubmit=async(object) =>{
        const fd = new FormData()
        fd.append('name', object.name)
        fd.append('category', object.category)
        fd.append('quantity', object.quantity)
        fd.append('price', object.price)
        fd.append('myFile',object.file[0], object.file[0].name)

const response = await axios.post(`${url}/admin/add-product`,fd)

}
```

model

```
    name:String,
    category:Number,
    quantity:Number,
    price:Number,
    image:String
```

server

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, 'images')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, Date.now() + '-' +file.originalname )
    }
  })
``
```

const upload = multer({ storage: storage })

```
route.post('/admin/add-product',upload.single('myFile'),addProduct)

export const addProduct = async (req, res)=>
{    
     try{

    
     }catch(error)
     {
         res.status(404).json({message:error.message})
     }
}
```

Comment: you want to save the image in the mongodb or in the server's file storage?

Comment: server's file storage

Answer (score 0):

```
const url = `http://localhost:2001`

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, 'images')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, file.originalname )
    }
  })

route.post('/admin/add-product',upload.single('file'), addProduct)

 const addProduct = async (req, res)=>
{
     try{
         const object = {name:req.body.name,category:req.body.category,quantity:req.body.quantity,price:req.body.price,image:req.file.filename  }
         if(!req.file)
         return res.status(404).json('image not found')

         const imageUrl = `${url}/admin/add-product/${req.file.filename}`
         
         const newProduct = new Product(object)
         await newProduct.save()

         return res.status(201).json(imageUrl)
    
     }catch(error)
     {
         res.status(404).json({message:error.message})
     }
}
```